# I want to return a different query instead of null

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
    sc.id AS cargo_id,
    sc.NAME AS cargo_name,
    cp.size AS package_name,
    cp.min AS min_range,
    cp.max AS max_range,
    cpp.price AS price,
    sc.contract 
FROM
    cargo_package_price cpp
    LEFT JOIN cargo_package cp ON cp.id = cpp.package_id
    LEFT JOIN `shipping_companies` sc ON sc.id = cpp.`cargo_id`
    LEFT JOIN b2b_users_cargo ON b2b_users_cargo.cargoid = cpp.`cargo_id` 
WHERE
    uid = 279 and 
    cp.min <= 20 AND cp.max > 20    
ORDER BY
    cpp.cargo_id,
    cp.max DESC
```

Hi everyone,
If the value in the Where condition returns empty, I want to return a different value. How can I do it ?

`cp.min <= 18 AND cp.max > 18`

When I enter a value below 20, the code works. When I enter a value over 20, the value returns blank.

I don't want it to go blank. When I type 22 I want to equal cp.max = 20

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please describe what do you mean by *If the value in the Where condition returns empty, I want to return a different value* ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean that if the query with `cp.min <= 18` return rows then you need in those rows only, but if it does not return rows then you need the result for a query with `cp.max > 18`?

Comment: @akina yes, if it's not returning value I want to equalize cp.max = 20

Comment: What is precise MySQL vesion?

Comment: my mysql version is 10.6.9-MariaDB-log thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Which table is `uid` in???  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Your sample rows do not allow for `cp.min_range < 21`, hence no rows returned.  Why are you expecting it to return something?

Comment: because I'm getting data from there, I need to do something. What I want to do is if the data is not returning I want to equal cp.max = 20

CREATE TABLE `b2b_users_cargo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cargoid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cargotopprice` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cargostatus` int(1) DEFAULT 1,
  `contract` int(255) DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2417 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3

Comment: Can't you handle this logic on application side? If result-set is empty then ...

Comment: I'm writing because I can't. Thank you if you help